# ReactJS: How can I change the link preview of a URL?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't know where to start with this, my default link preview for my site looks like this: 
[image]
I don't know why it's displaying bootstrap and not what is in my site. This is the page I am trying to share:

[image]

so I was expecting that the link would have the image and the title(blacked out).

But on the good side, when you click on the bootstrap link, it will redirect to my page and not to bootstrap but still what I cannot get is why is it displaying bootstrap and not what is on the page? Where can I change it?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is your question specifically about Facebook’s link previews?

Comment: @MTCoster no, I just made facebook posting as an example

Comment: Can you tell us the URL you’re testing?

Comment: here it is @MTCoster https://shop.medalert.ph/product/berry-minty-christmas

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is this line in your `<head>`:

```html
<link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/blog/">
```

This tells bots, web crawlers, and generally everyone that this page is exactly the same as https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/blog/. It even goes a step further and indicates that this is the *proper* URL for your page.

Most automated systems will stop parsing your page after seeing a `<link rel="canonical">` tag and instead parse the linked page *as though it was the current one*. This is where Facebook et al. are getting the Bootstrap metadata from.

**TL;DR:** Remove this line.

---

For future reference, you can use Facebook’s [Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fshop.medalert.ph%2Fproduct%2Fberry-minty-christmas) to troubleshoot problems like this. For the given URL, this is the current result:

[image: Facebook Sharing Debugger screenshot]

Note the **Canonical URL** and **Redirect Path** fields, which indicate my above diagnosis.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use something like [react-helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet) or [react-meta-tags](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-meta-tags) to set your `<head>` data correctly. The data you are looking to set would be openGraph data which can be found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the answer you were looking for but I was searching for how to update the info your react app shows when you preview the link in some other app. Every solution I tried wasn't working with github pages and react (react-helmet, react-meta-tags, react-document-meta). What ended up working was that you can edit the `index.html` located inside the `public` folder to change this info. Include this somewhere in the head:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/IMDB.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <title>IMDB</title>
    <meta property="og:audio" content="http://example.com/bond/theme.mp3" />
    <meta property="og:description" 
      content="Sean Connery found fame and fortune as the
               suave, sophisticated British agent, James Bond." />
    <meta property="og:determiner" content="the" />
    <meta property="og:locale" content="en_GB" />
    <meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="fr_FR" />
    <meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="es_ES" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="IMDb" />
    <meta property="og:video" content="http://example.com/bond/trailer.swf" />
```

Example from https://ogp.me/

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the [ogtag.me](https://app.ogtag.me) API that allows you to shorten your links dynamically and send the data you want it to display on social platforms and then use this shorten links in your share buttons.